# How to separate words from a row individually using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with a table called keywords -- see below
[image]

**** As you can see the row has more than one word listed inside.

**MY QUESTION**
Is there a way to separate each word on it's own using mysql and php. Right now it combines all the words as one instead of individually.

The picture below is showing you words but one button may contain 3 or more words.
[image]
I need for the words to be unique and on their own. Can this be done in MYSQL? If so can you please provide the php coding, thank you.

Comment: `$arrayOfWords = explode (",", $keywordsString);` this basically convert the long string into array . Then you can loop and display the single words as you wish .

Comment: `$uniqueArray=array_unique ($arrayOfWords);` this does the filtering to avoid repeating keywords .

Comment: @Ashraf actually it's better to `explode(", ", $str);` note the comma_space.

Comment: In a strict RDBMS sense, you don't have a table, so this isn't (yet) an SQL problem

Answer (score 1):

you can separate the keyword by comma and space using PHP.

```
//Split the keyword into array
$keywords_array = explode(", ", $keywords);

//Use array_unique to remove duplicates
$unique_keywords_array = array_unique($keywords_array);

//Print output
foreach($unique_keywords_array as $key) {
    echo $key . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Okay I see the code above can you help me apply it my code? I am not sure exactly how to plug this code in correctly.                                                                    <?php
$sql = mysqli_query($sample,"SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE $keywords_array = explode(", ", $keywords)
ORDER BY keywords");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
 $link = $row['link'];
 $keywords = $row['keywords'];
 
$unique_keywords_array = array_unique($keywords_array);

foreach($unique_keywords_array as $key) {
    echo "<a href='$link'>$key .</a><br />";
}
?>

Comment: `<?php $sql = mysqli_query($sample,"SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY keywords");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
 $link = $row['link'];
$keywords_array = explode(", ", $row['keywords']);
                                $unique_keywords_array = array_unique($keywords_array);
foreach($unique_keywords_array as $key) {
echo "<a href='" . $link . "'>" . $key . "</a><br />";
 }
} ?>`

Comment: Oh thank you for your patience and kindness and help. Thank you, awesome!!! It worked. :))

Comment: Okay now that I have this code (which it looks great by the way) how do I merge the words together to only show one. For example I have the word nation that shows up five times but I only need one. That one word (ex: nation) will then be linked to another page which will show all the post based on the word nation. Again thank you for your help, for you truly are helping :) https://livinghisword.org/php/articles/a-c2.php

Comment: `$all_keywords_array = array(); $sql = mysqli_query($sample,"SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY keywords"); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {    $keywords_array = explode(", ", $row['keywords']);    $unique_keywords_array = array_unique($keywords_array); foreach($unique_keywords_array as $key) {
// use empty to prevent null exception for the first keyword
// Check if current keyword is in $all_keywords_array
if ((empty($all_keywords_array)) || (!in_array($key, $all_keywords_array))) {
$all_keywords_array[] = $key;
echo "<a href='" . $row['link'] . "'>" . $key . "</a><br />";
} } }`

Comment: You need to have an array $all_keywords_array to store all the keywords (according to your database example above, $all_keywords_array will contain all the keywords: rude, awakening, persecution, protesting, amir, one, last days, prophecy, church, evil, sleeps, ...) so that you can check if the current keyword is in that array before printing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it and your time. God Bless!

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't share any code, i can give you a simple guess so you can proceed further :-

Get data from your table with php and use [explode](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) function to separate each word.

Answer (score 0):

the best choice is to use explode function , 
the link below is the reference of explode in php website : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php